# How do I get rid of sticky iPad splash screens?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Initially I developed my app as Universal. Then I designed splash screens separately for iPad. Recently I decided to deploy my app in iPhone device mode only. My app has no fancy graphics and it just looks well and works perfect on iPad either in 1x or 2x mode.

To do so I set `Devices` to `iPhone` at `TARGET/Summary/IOS Application Target` pane. I dragged new splash images I created for iPhone into `Launch images` placeholders, one for non-Retina and one for Retina displays.

However when I launch my iPhone app on the iPad, either through debugger or stand alone, the old iPad splash screens I no longer use come up. They look bad because the image centre appears to be moved down-right as they were originally created for iPad.

I went back to XCode and momentarily changed the `Device` type to `Universal or iPad`. I deleted the images both from `Launch images` placeholders and physically from the file system.

Unfortunately the iPad splash images I created earlier still come back when I build my app in iPhone device mode and deploy it on my iPad. How can I get rid of them once and for all and get the app use the iPhone launch images I created and setup recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clean your project (`Command+Shift+Option+K`)
2. Close Xcode, go to `~/yourCurrentUser/.Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
   Find the folder for your project, and delete it.
3. Delete the app in your simulator or test device.
4. Now build and run the app, and that must work; if not, delete the final images once more, and repeat the above steps.

**Don't forget to check your info.plist file for Icon Files key. Sometiems splash screen images get added to the Icon Files key for no clear reason! You must remove them from there.**

Comment: Neeku as indicated above (see my response to Ladislav) Clean all targets (in Xcode Product->Clean) fixed my problem. But your list seems more definitive and comprehensive. I'll bookmark it. Many thanks  for helping me and following it up.

Comment: Neeku. I came across another nasty issue with sticky icons and your response helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted the images from the disk, Clean all targets (in Xcode Product->Clean) and rebuild. There should be no way after doing this that the old image will appear (if it does it means it was not deleted properly from your project).

Comment: You should also clean the build folder (hold alt and click on the product menu), and delete the app from the test device.

Comment: Chance, many thanks for the handy tip as well. You guys are great. One day I just hope to become as knowledgeable to help others. Thanks :)